# Improving Stack Overflow's R tag wiki to reflect Cross Validated's R policy

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The Stack Overflow [r](/questions/tagged/r)  [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) does not carry the same information as the Cross Validated [r](/questions/tagged/r)  [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/r/info). The two are similar, but the Stack Overflow's tag wiki lacks any information about what questions should be asked.

I came across this when I found some R questions being tagged as off-topic since it involved a certain amount of statistics. I was simply looking to see if this was a valid close reason, that is off-topic because it belongs on a different site.

This seems like deliberate decision, but the excerpt includes:

> ...for statistical questions please use crossvalidated.com.

This does not completely explain how Cross Validated handles [r](/questions/tagged/r) questions.

Is there any reason why this information is missing? Is Stack Overflow's policy on R questions in conflict with Cross Validated's policy? Should the Stack Overflow tag wiki be improved?

Comment: Tag wikis are collaboratively edited, just like everything else. I imagine that the Stack Overflow wiki assumes the situation over on Cross Validated is rather simplistic because it wasn't a Cross Validated user who originally wrote it.

Comment: @CodyGray that seems plausible. I am just looking to see if anyone has any "inside" information and whether something should be done to the tag wiki.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, are you just asking whether the SO tag wiki should include a note about statistical analysis questions being more appropriate for CV, in addition to what's in the excerpt?

Comment: Statistical questions are on topic for CV - that's what it was set up for. The ambiguity is when you are *using* R to do those statistics. We don't want the statistics questions on [so] but do want the R programming questions. Likewise, CV doesn't want the "how do I use R to do X" questions; in some cases these might be better housed on [so]. We can do something to guide the former (which is what the tag wiki says), but we aren't in control of what CV wants to do and the R tag has to follow the general [so] guidelines.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any reason why this information is missing?

Tag wikis are a collaborate effort. The reason that this is not included is that (i) nobody thought it necessary or (ii) that nobody could be bothered to put it in. You seem to disagree with (i), but haven't made a suggestion.

> Is Stack Overflow's policy on R questions in conflict with Cross
>   Validated's policy?

I don't see any indication for that. In praxis we have hardly ever any problems with migration.

> Should the Stack Overflow tag wiki be improved?

There is always room for improvement. To steal from Wikipedia: Be bold and just edit it. We can always change it again or roll back. You might want to drop in in the R Public chat room and discuss it with the most active contributors to the R tag.